# Should this boxes for my custom Object Detector be smaller?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, data-science

[image: Example Image]

So Im trying to make a Object Detector for this companys forms, and we have labelled the images as shown in the example image I uploaded, my question is: Should We make more accurate boxes or is OK as they are, since the written part that we are trying to detect could be bigger.

So, what im asking is: In the example image, the "Descripcion" part or Description, has just 2 lines of text, but it could be more, should we make the box to just select the Description title + the 2 lines or so we stick to what we are doing now title + the 2 lines + all blank space that could have been filled with lines

Comment: Boxes seem too arbitrary. You either make them smaller to fit the text, to make network learn where there is text or you make boxes fit the regions, if your documents are all similar. In the case of regions, you could even classify the regions as description, import and such. I still think you can solve this particular image with just opencv though, should be easy to identify rectangle regions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you really want to do with the detected boxes. What are the next steps, can the next step e.g. extracting the text handle all the free space, or would it be better to just the the part where it is actually written.

Besides that right now in your example I find that most boxes are too big. The form is more or less already splitted in boxes and it could be better to make the boxes smaller and more accurate e.g.the box around IMPORTE and some amount in €. I would label this closer. So the box only contains the information you actually want and nothing else.

But as I said it really depends on the next step the boxes should be used for.

Comment: We want to take the detected box, and pass it through tesseract  to extract the text, then we apply regular expressions to the text and store it in a .csv so we have each of the form´s field(i.e. Direction,Amount...) in a column. So in short we want to put the information of the form recived in a csv threfore I think that as you said, we should put the boxes smaller to detect just what it is actually written to process it.